# Integration test with Bounded DbContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, integration-testing, structuremap

I'm using multiple `DbContext`(Bounded `DbContext`) in my application. So I have following codes:

```
public class EfUnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork where TContext : BaseDbContext, new()
{
   ...
}

//*******************************Module1**************************************
public interface IModule1UnitOfWork:IUnitOfWork
{
}
public class Module1EfUnitOfWork : EfUnitOfWork<Module1DbContext>,IModule1UnitOfWork
{
    public Module1EfUnitOfWork ()
        : base(new Module1DbContext())
    {
    }
}
public class Module1DbContext: BaseDbContext
{
    static Module1DbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Module1DbContext>(null);
    }

    public Module1DbContext()
        : base("name=MyDatabase") 
    {
    }    
}

//*******************************Module2**************************************
public interface IModule2UnitOfWork:IUnitOfWork
{
}
public class Module2EfUnitOfWork : EfUnitOfWork<Module2DbContext>,IModule2UnitOfWork
{
    public Module2DbContext()
        : base(new PlanningDbContext())
    {
    }
}
public class Module2DbContext: BaseDbContext
{
    static Module2DbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Module2DbContext>(null);
    }

    public Module1DbContext()
        : base("name=MyDatabase") 
    {
    }    
}
```

I'm using `StructureMap 3` as my `IoC container` too and used following codes:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>x.For(typeof(IModule1UnitOfWork))
                    .Use(typeof(Module1EfUnitOfWork))
                    .SetLifecycleTo((Lifecycles.Singleton));
                x.For(typeof(IUnitOfWork))
                    .Use(typeof(Module1EfUnitOfWork))
                    .SetLifecycleTo((Lifecycles.Singleton)));

ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>x.For(typeof(IModule2UnitOfWork))
                    .Use(typeof(Module2EfUnitOfWork))
                    .SetLifecycleTo((Lifecycles.Singleton));
                x.For(typeof(IUnitOfWork))
                    .Use(typeof(Module2EfUnitOfWork))
                    .SetLifecycleTo((Lifecycles.Singleton)));
```

It works fine, but when I want to use these codes for `Integration Test`, I have one problem.
I want to use `Sql Server CE` for my `Integration Test`, so I have to pass my test's `ConnectionString`(that specify the `Sql Server CE` database file) to the module's `DbContext`s, I used my module's `DbContexts` as Generic Parameters in the `EfUnitOfWork<>` class and so it should has parameterless constructor, but as you see I used my module's DbContext parameterless constructor for specifying my Database:

```
public Module1DbContext()
    : base("name=MyDatabase");
```

and couldn't pass anything to it.

So, how could I use my existing `DbContext`s for `Integration Test`?

Comment: name only designate a connection string, so it is an indirect parameter read from an app.config, so imho, you should just use a different app.config for your tests.

Comment: @tschmit007: you are correct, I tried it and worked fine:) thank you. please post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"name=" only designate a connection string, so it is an **indirect parameter** read from an app.config file.

So imho, you should just use a different app.config for your tests.